# Is this translation of a joke grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to translate this [Dutch comic](http://kalendercrisis.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/gummbah41.jpg) to English. I want to say that the probability of rain turns out to be higher than predicted, but that this probability is not of such magnitude that it actually rained. This is mathematical nonsense ofcourse, but that's the punchline of the joke.

My first attempt is: *"The probability of rain turned out to be higher than predicted, but not of a magnitude such that it actually rained that day."*

I can't figure out if this is grammatically correct or not. Does this make sense? Is there an easier, more concise way of explaining the joke in English?

Comment: Haha, dit is zo ongeveer de eerste keer dat ik Gummbah of how hij ook heet echt grappig vind.

Comment: To OP, the "chance of rain" that you see on TV or read about, is not actually a probability percentage. The percentage is the amount of land area that they computed (out of a sample size) that will get rain 100%. So the translation (and even the original statement) might not make semantic sense. EDIT: On the other hand, since I just read it is a joke, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: If you want to practice your English, and check if what you're saying is correct, and natural English, lang-8.com may be a good fit. (Disclaimer: I use the site) I'm not voting to close, but just letting you know if other people close this question.

Comment: @jsn, I know :) it also does not make sense mathematically, but that's the joke...

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, nice suggestion, thanks. I apologize if my question does not fit on this website.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think in English it *reads* better like this:

> "The chances of rain turned out to be higher than predicted, but not so high that it actually rained."

Of course, I can't read the original so I'm not sure how close it is.

Comment: Perfect! It is more than close enough.

Comment: Ahh, I actually thought of a sentence like this but thought it wasn't proper English! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Stijn: Your first attempt is also correct, but the language is much more formal. Formal language works well in a joke when the formal language *itself* is a *part* of the joke.

Comment: The form here is that of a weather bulletin, which usually is formal - specific words have well-defined meanings. However, that's no reason to pull out the dictionary. Generic weather bulletins often use a limited vocabulary, and e.g. "magnitude" isn't in there. "High chance" is. The joke here is of course that formally "chance" is used to refer to the probability of a future event, and here it's used for a past event (todays rain).

Comment: weliswaar=indeed, ook weer niet=but then again not

Comment: @mplungjan: *Wel(iswaar)* is perhaps the most difficult Dutch word to translate into English ever!

Comment: Nah, not really. indeed or admittedly will suffice here

Comment: Semantically, it's not good - one works out or estimates rather than predicts probabilities (which are predictions themselves).

Comment: Who are you commenting on, @EdwinAshworth

Comment: I didn't want to rain on anyone's parade, so I pointed out the illogicality somewhere along the thread. Though if Groucho had come out with "The chances of rain turned out to be higher than predicted, but not so high that it actually rained," I admit I'd have laughed.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit late to the party, but I feel obliged to point out that the correct translation of _verwacht_ is _forecast_, not _predicted_.

Answer (score 2):

My version

> The chance of rain was indeed/admittedly higher than predicted, but then again not high enough for it to have actually rained that day

Answer (score 0):

My take:

> The chance of rain was indeed higher than predicted, but also not so
>   high that it actually rained that day.